# HTML - browser error --> Can't find variable: Firebase

Tags: html, firebase, web, initialization

@jdv the error in the attached screenshot is being displayed in my browser's debugger  [image: browser debugger error]

NOTE: Firebase DOES initializes in my command line - but my text editor will NOT accept the INITIALIZATION CODE (see code below). I love being challenged, but after 2 1/2 days of not finding a fix, I need help!

For some strange reason, **config** (in bold text below) is highlighted yellow in my text editor (I'm using brackets).

Here is some of my code:

```
<script src="/__/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>My App Title</title>

<script src="/__/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var **config** = {
        apiKey: "myapi",
        authDomain: "myappname.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://myappname.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "myprojectid",
        storageBucket: "myappname.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "mysenderid",
    };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Perhaps someone can tell me what I am doing wrong. I am brand new to coding, so I beg your pardon if this is an easy fix :) -lion

---

Still searching for a solution....

Here is a screenshot of my code:

[image: firebase initialization code]

Thanks for all the helpful suggestions :) -lion

Comment: add a comma  `"mysenderid",`

Comment: @Peter thanks for catching that :) Unfortunately, that didn't fix my issue. Cheers!

Comment: @Peter thanks again, but that didn't fix the issue. After thinking about it, I need to revise my question / issue...one sec. I beg your pardon for my lack of clarity.

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to inspect the deployed script. It might tell you what is wrong with the invocation. But if anyone can help you they will probably need to see the error or warning the editor is trying to tell you.

Comment: @jdv thanks for the suggestion! I found the error, and will upload it in one sec - nothing like progress :)

Comment: @jdv just uploaded a screenshot of the error. Do you have any idea as to why my text editor-->  "Can't find variable: Firebase" ...?

Comment: There is a fundamental import issue here. All that script stuff at the top is not actually bringing in the firebase object, or it is not in the right scope. I'm not sure which, but the docs for firebase do talk about the different ways you can get at the object in Javascript.

Comment: @jdv thanks for the feedback - digging in the weeds now lol. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
    <script src="/__/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've tried entering the scripts both ways, and my text editor still won't accept the firebase initialization code. Will continue to search for the answer :)

Comment: Are you using these script tags on the head or body of your HTML files?

Comment: Initially I placed them at the bottom...then I tried them at the top. I just removed ALL scripts, and now I will try to place the firebase script at the bottom, and position ALL other scripts below it. The issue I am having is that my text editor refuses to accept the firebase initialization code.

Comment: just added a screenshot of my code. Feel free to let me know if you see anything I'm doing wrong - I have much to learn :) Thanks!